# UK spouse visa application

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I would like to apply for a spouse visa for myself and my daughter after my fiancé and I get married in August this year.

We have been dating for 2 years now and have been visiting each other back and forth. He is British and he meets the financial requirements.

I would like to know if its ok to submit the application immediately after we get the marriage certificate, and which documents we need to provide to prove our relationship (apart from the marriage certificate).

Comment: Is your fiancee the father of your daughter?

Comment: No am the sole provider for her
And she is 4 years

Comment: Since your financé is not your daughter's father, you may be suspected of a marriage of convenience.  The usual evidence to show yours is not a marriage of convenience would be any record of your relationship during the two years before your wedding.  People usually speak of photographs, e-mail and message logs, phone records, that sort of thing.